# How to convert row values to attributes (columns) in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, attributes

I have a dataset in pandas with column pid (patient id), and code (drug code), sorted in rows as the example shows. I need to convert them to 1 patient/row, and list all the drugs as attributes for each patient.

What I have now:

```
pid  code
1    Az
1    Bn
2    Az
2    Bn
2    C4
3    Bn
3    C4
3    Dx
4    Az
4    Bn
4    Dx
4    E
5    C4
5    Dx
5    E
```

I need to convert it to:

```
pid  Az   Bn   C4   Dx   E
1    y    y    n    n    n
2    y    y    y    n    n
3    n    y    y    y    n
4    y    y    n    y    y
5    n    n    y    y    y
```

Comment: See Answer to question # 9 https://stackoverflow.com/a/47152692/2336654

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC  `crosstab`

```
pd.crosstab(df.pid,df.code).replace({1:'y',0:'n'})
Out[231]: 
code Az Bn C4 Dx  E
pid                
1     y  y  n  n  n
2     y  y  y  n  n
3     n  y  y  y  n
4     y  y  n  y  y
5     n  n  y  y  y
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is to [pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe) your dataframe

```
new_df = df.assign(values='y').pivot(index='pid', columns='code', values='values').replace({None:'n'})

>>> new_df
code Az Bn C4 Dx  E
pid                
1     y  y  n  n  n
2     y  y  y  n  n
3     n  y  y  y  n
4     y  y  n  y  y
5     n  n  y  y  y
```

Answer (score 2):

Having fun!

### Fun 1

Create a Series with a MultiIndex and unstack

```
pd.Series('y', df.values.T.tolist()).unstack(fill_value='n')

  Az Bn C4 Dx  E
1  y  y  n  n  n
2  y  y  y  n  n
3  n  y  y  y  n
4  y  y  n  y  y
5  n  n  y  y  y
```

---

### Fun 2

Use defaultdict

```
d = defaultdict(dict)

for i, p, c in df.itertuples():
    d[c][p] = 'y'

pd.DataFrame(d).fillna('n')

  Az Bn C4 Dx  E
1  y  y  n  n  n
2  y  y  y  n  n
3  n  y  y  y  n
4  y  y  n  y  y
5  n  n  y  y  y
```

---

### Fun 3

```
i, r = pd.factorize(df.pid)
j, c = pd.factorize(df.code)
e = np.empty((len(r), len(c)), str)
e.fill('n')
e[i, j] = 'y'
pd.DataFrame(e, r, c)

  Az Bn C4 Dx  E
1  y  y  n  n  n
2  y  y  y  n  n
3  n  y  y  y  n
4  y  y  n  y  y
5  n  n  y  y  y
```